# How do you set a parametric EQ to emulate a Dunlop Crybaby wah?

Tags: guitar-effects

How do you set a parametric EQ to emulate a Dunlop Crybaby wah? What frequency bands and Q values should be used?

Comment: A parametric eq will boost/defeat certain bandwidths at the setting it's put at. Any wah will sweep through several of these, so the two things are separate entities, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google search turned up this image from Electrosmash.com.  I see no harm in assuming it's accurate until proven otherwise.

[image: Cry baby frequency response]

Simply use one band pass filter with a bandwidth that roughly matches this image, and move the frequency center around between 450-2000Hz, roughly, to get the wah sound.

If you're working in a DAW, you can get further accuracy by linking bandwidth to frequency center, so that the bandwidth is slightly greater at higher frequencies, matching the behavior of the pedal.

Comment: https://www.electrosmash.com/crybaby-gcb-95

Comment: "The frequency response is characterized by a resonant peak centered in 750 Hz (with the variable resistor VR1 at mid position). The peak sweeps up and down from 450 Hz to 1.6 kHz. The selected frequencies are amplified up to 18dB while the surrounding ones are attenuated" Ibid.

Comment: @empty useful excerpt.  Although I don't think the 18db bit matters as it's the shape of the frequency response that matters-  If you can match the shape, then the 18dB peak just describes the overall gain of the system.

Comment: Ranges of various Crybabys. https://www.sweetwater.com/feature/dunlop/wah-pedals/index.php